# How to conditionally plot in gnuplot with missing or invalid data?

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, gnuplot, missing-data

In gnuplot (I'm using 5.1 CVS) one can specify missing data (`set datafile missing '?'` for example) and gnuplot also knows invalid data (like `NaN` or `1/0`).

How can I conditionally react to them? If my data has one of them I *sometimes* (i.e. on some columns, but not on all) want to do something else instead of just skipping them. So, basically I want to say (pseudocode)

```
plot 'datafile' using 1:($2 = MISSING ? $3+$4 : $2 )
```

I can use `strcol(2)` to check the column content, but this does not work for the string specified by missing `set datafile missing '?'` because the string specified by `set datafile missing` seems to have a higher "importance", because I can't check it using `colstr()` (gnuplot stops handling the datapoint before it even comes to evaluating `strcol()`).

My data can have missing data in several columns. If it is, for example, missing in column 2 I just want a gap in the data (like it's invalid), but if it is in column 3 I want it to plot something else instead and not leaving a gap.

For invalid data (like the pre-defined `NaN`) this works perfectly fine. It is skipped when appearing in the data, but I can also react to it by saying `strcol(2) == 'NaN' ? $3+$4 : $2`. So for invalid data, gnuplot first evaluates `strcol()` if (and only if) it is there.

I can simulate this behaviour by using two "missing chars", one that I use for `set datafile missing` and another one that I use for `strcol()` checks. But this is an ugly workaround, I would have to edit my datafiles and replacing half of the missing chars by hand. Is there a way to handle missing also data conditionally, like one can handle invalid data?

Comment: I can't look into this right now but perhaps awk allows you more flexibility preprocessing your data: plot "< awk processing options datafile"

Comment: @Miguel I'm on Windows, so I don't have awk.

Comment: No, as far as I know there is now way to handle missing data in the `using` statement. I had also wished to have something like this. Would be worth to open a feature request.